# onDestroy() Doesn't get called all the time

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle, ondestroy

I'm creating a temp file in the application. And when the app is destroyed I need to delete that file. Currently I'm calling this `deleteTempFile()` method in the `onDestroy()` method. But as I found out in the developers guide its not guaranteed to be called when app is killed. What should be the correct way of achieving this?

Note that `onDestroy` is not called when we press home button and then long press it again to get the task manager and swipe the app to kill it.

Comment: It's difficult to identify the app destroy state. Will it be suitable for you to remove/restore file when app goes background/foreground?

Comment: Problem is when I play that temp file using a video player, the app goes to the background. I shouldn't delete it at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it in onSaveBundleInstances(Bundle outBundle)

Comment: onSaveBundleInstances is called when the activity is paused. Similar to onPause. But I need the temp file until the app is killed. It's actually a video file. So within my app there's a feature to play it using video players. But even when we launch those video players onSaveBundleInstances and onPause is called.

Comment: The thing is, you can guarantee a call for onDestroy(), so onSaveBundleInstances() is the safest event, or else you'll have to figure out some work around for it. :)

Comment: Seems like I may have to use onSaveBundleInstances to achieve this. But have to distinguish between many call backs I get

Answer (score 0):

onDestroy() will not work all time so alternate way is you should use onBackPressed() method for deleteTempFile().

Comment: I'm not killing the app using the back key. I press home button and then long press it again to get the task manager and swipe the app to kill it. That's the scenario.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
   super.onPause()
   if (isFinishing())
      deleteTempFile();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my situation I press the home button first. So I get onPause with isFinishing() = false. Then when I swipe to kill the app I don't get onPause again.